# Static build of Asterisk 11 on Debian 8 failing

Tags: asterisk

I am attempting to do a static build Asterisk 11 under Debian 8. I have downloaded the sources etc. and think I have satisfied all the packages required for the various dependencies, but am getting the following when I `make`

```
   ...
   [CC] recno/rec_delete.c -> recno/rec_delete.o
   [CC] recno/rec_get.c -> recno/rec_get.o
   [CC] recno/rec_open.c -> recno/rec_open.o
   [CC] recno/rec_put.c -> recno/rec_put.o
   [CC] recno/rec_search.c -> recno/rec_search.o
   [CC] recno/rec_seq.c -> recno/rec_seq.o
   [CC] recno/rec_utils.c -> recno/rec_utils.o
   [AR] hash/hash.o hash/hash_bigkey.o hash/hash_buf.o hash/hash_func.o hash/hash_log2.o hash/hash_page.o hash/ndbm.o btree/bt_close.o btree/bt_conv.o btree/bt_debug.o btree/bt_delete.o btree/bt_get.o btree/bt_open.o btree/bt_overflow.o btree/bt_page.o btree/bt_put.o btree/bt_search.o btree/bt_seq.o btree/bt_split.o btree/bt_utils.o db/db.o mpool/mpool.o recno/rec_close.o recno/rec_delete.o recno/rec_get.o recno/rec_open.o recno/rec_put.o recno/rec_search.o recno/rec_seq.o recno/rec_utils.o -> libdb1.a
   [LD] astdb2sqlite3.o db1-ast/libdb1.a -> astdb2sqlite3
   [CC] astdb2bdb.c -> astdb2bdb.o
   [LD] astdb2bdb.o db1-ast/libdb1.a -> astdb2bdb
   [CC] chan_local.c -> chan_local.o
   [LD] chan_local.o -> chan_local.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtbeginT.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `__TMC_END__' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtbeginT.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/src/asterisk-11/Makefile.rules:170: recipe for target 'chan_local.so' failed
make[1]: *** [chan_local.so] Error 1
Makefile:397: recipe for target 'channels' failed
make: *** [channels] Error 2
```

I am really struggling to understand what is happening here. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you do STATIC, use rhel. It should work on debian after that. If you want build for debian, use dynamic or dynamic+chroot.

Comment: Hmm. The target system is actually openSUSE. Out of curiosity why would I be able to do a standalone build on RHEL but not on Debian? (I suspect it will actually be easier, given looming deadlines, to do a dynamically-linked build on an openSUSE platform).

Comment: Sure you can do static build on ANY OS including custom let-me-create-my-linux or other. But issue is: asterisk tested on RHEL first. So VERY likly you have no issue on rhel at all. You can also do dynamic build, after that do ldd and see dependencies/create chroot.

Comment: If you really want do it on debian, rebuild that lib from source with PIC.